# Kubuntu not starting with RX 6650 XT

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, kde, amdgpu

System does not make it into login screen with a RX 6650 XT installed: black screen. tty is available. `startx` does nothing. 'Trying' (instead of installing) Kubuntu with the live media also fails with the same problem.
However, recovery mode works and lets me work with a desktop. And generally, the system works fine with either the previously installed Nvidia card or even the iGPU.

In preparation to installing the new card, I switched to the nouveau drivers from the proprietary Nvidia ones (version 515). Then I swapped out the cards, and was greeted by a black screen. I tried various things trying to get it to work with the new card:

- purging anything nvidia
- uninstall nouveau firmware
- install drivers from amd website
- reinstall latest kernel
- reinstall xorg & sddm

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-52-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics
Memory: 15,6 GiB
```

I was able to install the new card in Windows without any issues. The card works.

---

Is Navi 23 even supported in 20.04? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMDGPU-Driver only gives a question mark. Also, `/lib/firmware/amdgpu/` contains no files for Navi 23?
Edit: the drivers for that card are named "dimgrey cavefish" and are included.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it on Kubuntu 2**2**.04 and it works. But the performance in games is absolutely abysmal and unacceptable; like half the FPS of the old GTX 1660 Ti.

Comment: Check it's actually running accelerated driver by running `glxinfo`. Also AMD RDNA2 on Linux the driver hasn't yet finetuned the power scaling so it's quite possible it's running in low power mode if the game isn't very demanding. The workaround is to manually set it yo performance (see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1500) or use a tool like corectrl (https://gitlab.com/corectrl/corectrl)

Comment: @MatiasNGoldberg Thanks, you put me on the right track. Turns out the card's core frequency was limited to 500 MHz, and the memory was limited to 1000 MHz. I could set and thus "fix" the core clock speeds with corectrl, but I did not see an option to set the memory speed - so it's still borked (and I'm not going to dive into sys/class/drm/whatever in an attempt to hopefully fix it).

Comment: You may want to open a ticket in the Mesa bug tracker, or perhaps first try the latest Linux kernel. From what I can see the GPU came out 1 month ago, so it's quite possible Linux drivers weren't updated as to how to control the card's frequency.